# JDO Local Transaction Management

Tags: transactions, jdo

In JDO in the situation described below, After `methodB()` is executed (which has been called from `methodA()` ), if an exception occurs in `methodA()` will the rollback take place for the code both in `methodA()` and `methodB()` or just `methodA()` as in `methodB()` commit has already taken place.
Note: PersistenceManager is created on demand and stored in ThreadLocal

```
methodA() {
    PersistenceManager mgr = getPersistenceManager(  );
    Transaction trans;

    trans = mgr.currentTransaction(  );
    try {
        trans.begin(  );
        methodB();

        //some delete/update code
        // An exception occurs

        trans.commit(  );        
    }
    catch( Exception e ) {
        e.printStackTrace(  );
    }
    finally {
        if( trans.isActive(  ) ) {
            trans.rollback(  );
        }
        mgr.close(  );
    }
}

methodB() {
    PersistenceManager mgr = getPersistenceManager(  );
    Transaction trans;

    trans = mgr.currentTransaction(  );
    try {
        trans.begin(  );
        //code
        trans.commit(  );        
    }
    catch( Exception e ) {
        e.printStackTrace(  );
    }
    finally {
        if( trans.isActive(  ) ) {
            trans.rollback(  );
        }
        mgr.close(  );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transactions are not nested, they are independent. The PMs are different so the txns are different. One fails it rolls back, and is nothing to do with the other one

Comment: Got it ... this means if we use the same PM then both methods would have rolled back.

Comment: if you had used the same PM then you only have one transaction (as per what you would see by reading the JDO spec), and you would have got an exception when you called tx.begin() on a transaction that was already started (so you clearly never tried this)

Comment: I have not tried this yet, however was trying to figure out how to structure code so that when a transactional methodB is called from from another transactional methodA both methods belong to the same transaction and when the methodB is called independently even then it can still be transactional.

Comment: Apparently before calling tx.begin() in every method, I should be checking for tx.isActive() before calling tx.begin().

Answer (score 0):

methodA and methodB are part two different transaction i.e non atomic transaction reason : -

1> using same PM instance for two different transaction also doesn't ensure two different transaction are using same transaction instance id always due to there is no guarantee that nested method B object to be persisted is in 'persistance-clean' state always (side effects of persisting object in dirty state) and 
Method B transaction is in not getting propagated to method A as before , it's getting commited before then returing to A again.

2> **transaction is not contextual** and hence transaction will never be commited for the whole session or method sequence.

3> As referenced from spring template , for a particular transaction only once the transaction instance are always retrieved and whole the whole transaction is completed then only it's commited ,([it's also indirectly mentioned in jdo document indirectly : 
  [1]: http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_4_1/jdo/transactions.html#spring). One possible way would be, method A should act as a subject or observer for transaction here and method B should be a subscriber and when all the subscriber are notified against a particular transaction , then the transaction should be committed.

For more please refer : [Patterns for propagating changes to nested objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10136617/patterns-for-propagating-changes-to-nested-objects][1])